# GeoDjango installation attempt #5....the struggle continues

Tags: django, postgresql, gdal, geodjango, proj

Using OSGeo4W install, version 2.579.

I am installing GeoDjango on windows from [GeoDjango Installation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows). It hung up in the "**Modify Windows environment**" section: reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "%PATH%"

Does anyone know what this line of code does or why I am getting an invalid syntax error? The two commands that follow it executed successfully.

[image]

I think this might be a problem with environment variables here, Control Panel\System and Security\System. I've been messing with the relevant path as I attempt to do the installation.

[image]

I am an idiot. Please be gentle. I think that I don't know how to work with my system paths. Thanks a bunch! I need to know how to set System paths. Any relevant resources welcome.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? It might sound stupid, but can be all that is needed for env variables to be recognized...

Comment: I have done that a couple times. But, that is definitely worth another try. :)

Comment: Well, sorry for not being a better help here, I'm lost when it gets to windows! :) But you should not call yourself an idiot! It is normal to be lost! Hopefully you can fix your issue or someone comes along that can help you!

Comment: I'm holding out hope, jojo! Thanks for the encouragement, I'll need it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, I was so afraid to touch the registry, I wouldn't change any of these commands or path names from what was recommended in the Documentation. But, I got up the guts and just fixed the paths, I guess. The ship is saved!

[image]

[image]